# The question feed shows raw XML in Chrome

Tags: bug, feed

I am not sure if this is a bug, but the 'recent questions'/'questions' feed button:

> [image: 'Recent questions feed' hyperlink]

that is present on the bottom right side on most communities is not showing a parsed feed in Google Chrome.

I tried it on IE and it seems to work:

[image: Parsed XML feed in IE]

But in Chrome (v73) it shows the raw XML:

[image: Raw XML in Chrome]

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Your tags seem fine :) I've edited the post to make it a bit clearer, and added in some screenshots. Do you know if this ever 'worked' in Chrome? It might be that Chrome doesn't parse XML feeds but IE does (but I'm not sure!)

Comment: It's one of the reasons I use Chrome to debug OData requests - other browsers try to interpret them as RSS feeds ...